# Communication between fragments with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

Let's say I have two fragments A,B,C.
Fragment A contains fragments B,C with a View Pager the allows to switch between the two fragments by using tab layout.
Fragments B,C were created by using data from fragment A, Therefore I could pass a Listener from fragment A to fragments B and C and Receive events In those fragments in fragment A.
However I want to receive events in fragments B,C That occurred on Fragment A (Clicking on an item of the toolbar of A).

How could I pass send An event from fragment A to fragments B,C in a similar way as the listener that was passed from fragment A To fragment B that allowed B to send events to A.
If it is not possible with a listener it would be great to hear other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution to your problem is rather simple .Store the current fragment in a variable from Viewpager adapter getItem() method.

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragB=new FragB();
                return fragB;
            case 1:
                fragC = new FragC();
                return fragC;
        }
    }
```

Now when u wan to send data to fragment B and fragment C use this variables and send data to this fragments (Create method in fragment to handle the events). For example send event of button click.

```
  view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
           fragB.onClick();
           fragC.onClick();
    }
  });
```